# Webpack inline CSS background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack to load images and can't seem to get it working. My configuration looks like this:

```
var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: "/build/",
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader : 'url-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

And I am trying to use as an inline CSS background image like this:

```
<div class="inner-panel"
     style="background-image: url("/common/img/split-image/image.jpg");">
</div>
```

Also it doesn't work as an inline image:

```
<img src="/common/img/split-image/image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with your image paths, not with your webpack config.

Try putting a `./` at the start of your path like so

```
"./common/img/split-image/image.jpg"
```

Other then that you should look at your file requires as well and make sure there are placing them where you want to place them.

Since you are using file-loader (and I think React as well), an example of how you would use it would be:

```
//CJS
var file = require("file!./file.png");
//ES6
import file from "file!./file.png";

//Later inside a React component
    const inStyle = {
        background-image: 'url(' + file + ')'
    }
    <div style={inStyle}/>
```

(React takes objects rather then strings for the style attribute)

url-loader should be the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the files are being loaded at all though. How can I configure the file requires?

Comment: I'll modify my comment with more info about file-loader.

Comment: I had to remove the file! from the import to get this to work, but its working now. Really appreciate your help @DogPawHat